# Replicating an Icon in Google Maps API V3

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this code written in V2 API:

```
// replicate a different sized icon
    var babyIcon = new google.maps.Icon(marker.getIcon());

    babyIcon.iconSize = new google.maps.Size(
        marker.getIcon().iconSize.width * this.iconScale_,
        marker.getIcon().iconSize.height * this.iconScale_
    );

    babyIcon.iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point (
        marker.getIcon().iconAnchor.x * this.iconScale_,
        marker.getIcon().iconAnchor.y * this.iconScale_ / 2
    );
```

however, I can't get to convert this into v3 knowing that there is no Icon constructor for the v3 API. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use **MarkerImage** instead of Icon (getIcon() will return MarkerImage)

Here is the [Reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage)

```
var babyIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(marker.getIcon());

babyIcon.size = new google.maps.Size(
    marker.getIcon().size.width * this.iconScale_,
    marker.getIcon().size.height * this.iconScale_
);

babyIcon.anchor= new google.maps.Point (
    marker.getIcon().anchor.x * this.iconScale_,
    marker.getIcon().anchor.y * this.iconScale_ / 2
);
```